# What version of PhantomJS introduced bind support?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

What version of PhantomJS introduced bind support?

Was it version 2.0?

Comment: Yes, v2.0 introduces .bind and allows us to stop using polyfills :D

Comment: Yes/No questions are not a good fit for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhantomJS 2.

you might be interested in reading:

- [#10522](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10522)